# Accessing state from effects in Angular 8 app

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am working with Metronic which is a starter/admin site written in Angular.

What I am trying to do is load a specific set of data using the authenticated user's id.

This is my effect:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectEffects {

    @Effect()
    loadAllProjects$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType<AllProjectsRequested>(ProjectActionTypes.AllProjectsRequested),
            withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(allProjectsLoaded))),
            filter(([action, isAllProjectsLoaded]) => !isAllProjectsLoaded),

            mergeMap(() => this.projectService.getProjectsByOwnerId(4)),

            map(result => {
                return new AllProjectsLoaded({projects: result});
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                console.debug("error [%s]", error); 
                return of({ results: null });
            })      
          );

    @Effect()
    init$: Observable<Action> = defer(() => {
        return of(new AllProjectsRequested());
    });

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private projectService: ProjectService, private store: Store<AppState>) { }

}
```

This is my selector:

```
export const currentUser = createSelector(
    selectAuthState,
    auth => auth.user
);
```

The trouble I am having is how to grab the current user from store and pass the user.id value into this.projectService.getProjectsByOwnerId(n).

I've tried numerous combinations of

> this.user$ = this.store.pipe(select(currentUser))

and subscribing to the observable without any luck.

What's the "proper" way to access currentUser from the store in a synchronous manner?

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you can use `withLatestFrom`, like you did with `allProjectsLoaded`.

An example:

```
@Effect()
getOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<GetOrder>(ActionTypes.GetOrder),
  withLatestFrom(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      this.store.pipe(select(getOrders))
    )
  ),
  filter(([{payload}, orders]) => !!orders[payload.orderId])
  mergeMap([{payload}] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

See https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects for more info.